# Using Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000); multiple times on a single document

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I am very new to this and I am trying to learn some of the most basic things. One of these basic things is running the `Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);` code repeatedly on a single page *without* the `onclick` format. I have found it in multiple places where a button is the primary method of retrieval, but this is something that I'm trying to have automatically generated in multiple sections when the page loads.

This super simple code will function only once for me on a page (which makes sense with that whole using an id once thing):

```js
document.getElementById("DLID").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
```

When I combine it with the HTML:

```html
<span id="DLID"></span>
```

And I get a result of:

```
941907
```

Which is perfect and exactly what my goal was.

Now, I am attempting to repeat this (with differing outputs) in several `span` tags throughout a document. So I approached it with the solution to change `document.getElementById("DLID").innerHTML` to `document.getElementsByClassName("DLID").innerHTML` thinking that would apply to the entirety of the document. Instead, it didn't work at all and I was left with a large empty space of nothingness.

My complete and total inexperience in this has left me staring at the wall while I try to piece it together.

If anyone can assist this not-really-old-but-old lady in her learning, it would be much appreciated.

(Edit: I failed to mention that I made sure to change all instances of `id="DLID"` to `class="DLID"` )

Comment: There is no `.getElementsByClass()` method, it's `.getElementsByClassName()`, and it returns a **list** of elements. You'll have to iterate through the list and update each element individually.

Comment: Ah, yes. That was a mistake on my part when typing up my question. I checked my document and verified that I did put in `.getElementsByClassName()` and edited the question. Sorry (and thank you!)!

Comment: if you don't use `onclick` `click event` to detect any click,
then how do you know when to do that action? a timer? also, use innerHTML to edit text is not recommended, unless it's a pure text element, or it will destroy all other elements inside it, leaving only the text you updated

Comment: Are you adding random numbers to existing nodes or creating new nodes?

Comment: I am attempting to get it to automatically generate when the page loads, and it's purely text. It serves as a simple visual display with no other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// this gets an iterable of all elements with a class of "DLID"
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("DLID");

// you can use for..of to iterate over the elements. Don't use array methods like forEach on elements, elements is NOT an array.
for( let element of elements )
  element.innerText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
```

```css
span {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span><span class='DLID'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `.getElementByClassName()`, it returns an array of objects. You would have to loop through this array adding the random number to each one, i.e.

<s>```
document.getElementByClassName("DLID").forEach(item => {
  item.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
}
```</s>

EDIT: Forgot that you can't use `forEach` on HTMLCollections, the correct way (and I tested) is:

```
const dlidList = document.getElementsByClassName("DLID");
for (let item of dlidList) {
    item.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution anyone using interval to get diffrent random numbers is just bad practice and unoptimized, basically bad code

Comment: It's `getElementsByClassName`. You missed an s.

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I cannot get this to work for me either. I tried adding the 's' at the end of "Element" too.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("DLID")` doesn't return an array. So you can't use forEach either. I dropped in a corrected answer.

Comment: That's because it's my mistake. Forgot you can't do forEach over HTMLCollections. The correct way would be ```const dlidList = document.getElementsByClassName("DLID");
for (let item of dlidList) {
    item.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
}```

Comment: @Kyruski You are an angel! Thank you! 
Now I can stare at it and try to decode it all in my head and why it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

More commonly used in practice is [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
it's use css selector to specify the elements you want to acquire
If you are not familiar with it, you can check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```js
let count = 0;
function rand(){
    document.querySelectorAll(".DLID").forEach(element=>{
        element.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    });
    count++;
    if(count > 10) clearInterval(timer);
}
let timer = setInterval(rand, 1000);
```

```html
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in these few lines with `Array.from()`

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("DLID")).forEach(function(dlid) {
  dlid.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
});
```

```html
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
<span class="DLID"></span><br>
```